# Problem identifying Bluetooth ICs

Tags: circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, datasheet, bluetooth

**Backstory:**

Last week, I found a Bluetooth speaker that has a radio feature. I tried changing the charging port that was broken (because I wanted to take a look inside) and replacing the battery with the power supply. I ended up over-voltaging them and one of the chips broke. That IC was controlling the device. I googled the chip name "UAF873" and unrelated things pop up. I added the "UAF873 datasheet" and received several PDFs with "almost" similar results.

[Google result 1](https://datasheetspdf.com/datasheet/MB87073.html)

[Google result 2](http://www.datasheet.hk/view_download.php?id=1032369&file=0007%5Cuaf1780_60873.pdf)

First I thought it was the first PDF, but I got confused; I found another PDF with a similar name. So I checked the first one. I thought this is the correct name. I looked at my old PCB and found another one with the AB20bBPon it (it has 8 pins too.) So I took it and ignored it.

**Issue:**
The issue was that the AB20BP has burn marks on it like this:

[image: ab20bp with burnt marks?]

Here's the original chip:

[image: UAF873]

I found a Bluetooth USB chip that was supposed to plug them into non-Bluetooth speakers with the same code:

[image: UEA127]

**Question:**

The Bluetooth USB doesn't have the radio feature. If I use the Bluetooth USB chip I will risk breaking one of my circuits. I don't know about the AB20BP having the radio feature, but which IC should I install? I have trouble recognizing the AB20 IC. Please tell me which is the correct one.

I also think that the UAF and UEA are programmable chips but I don't know.

**edit:** I think the UAF, UEA chips are programmable, because it is a programmed chip. [This datasheet](https://datasheetspdf.com/datasheet/MB87073.html) explains this all. I  found another IC by [the assembler XingQiuZhiLian.](http://bbs.ntpcb.com/read.php?tid-121346-page-e.html)

Comment: If they're programmable ICs, it's unlikely you'll be able to get it working by just replacing them. You'd need the appropriate code to load onto them.

Comment: Your datasheet links all go to things that have nothing to do with Bluetooth.  The forum thread with the Bluetooth device doesn't show all the pictures for me - maybe you have to join the forum to see them.

Comment: `I received several PDFs with "almost" similar results` ... no, you didn't ... look at the results again

Comment: thats why i added the quotes there...